# Error parsing date string with `new Date`

Tags: javascript, date

```
datefromJSON = req.body.occasion_date;
occasion_date = new Date(datefromJSON);
console.log(occasion_date);

//while running this i get log like this 
//"Invalid Date"
```

when i get json data from req.body then save in datefromJSON var, and for storing into database i use to convert into Date object that get error

Comment: What do you get if you `console.log(datefromJSON)` before converting it to a date? - Perhaps what is happening is you are trying to pass `undefined` into `new Date`

Comment: use this function dateFormat(jsonDate, "dd/mm/yyyy");

Comment: 31-08-2016 
and after i get NaN

Answer (score 3):

Your date string (<s>whatever it is</s> `"31-08-2016"`) isn't in a format recognized by the `Date` constructor. So you ended up with a `Date` whose underlying time value is `NaN`, which is shown as "Invalid Date" when you ask for the string version. Gratuitous example:

```js
console.log(new Date("foobar").toString());
```

The **only** formats the specification requires a JavaScript implementation to support are:

- The one added in the ES5 specification in 2009, which was meant to be (and as of all recent specifications actually is; there was an error in ES5 and ES2015/ES2016) a subset of ISO-8601. (This is the format produced by `toISOString`.) [spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format)
- The ones produced by the `toString` and `toUTCString` (aka `toGMTString`) methods. [spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date.parse)

So for instance:

```js
console.log(new Date("2016-08-31T09:25").toString());
```

Every JavaScript implementation I've run into also *unofficially* supports parsing the U.S. format with slashes, `MM/dd/yyyy`, (even in non-U.S. locales), but the timezone varies (most interpret it as local time, others interpret it in GMT).

So you'll need to either:

A) Parse your string (regular expressions, `split`, etc.) and use the form of the `Date` constructor that supports supplying the parts individually. Mind the gotcha that the months value starts with 0 = January (not 1 = January). There are several dozen questions with examples of that here on SO. Here's an example of parsing the common `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss` or `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS` format as a local date/time:

Regex-based:

```js
function parseIt(str) {
  var rex = /^\s*(\d{1,2})[\/-](\d{1,2})[\/-](\d{4})(?: (\d{1,2})(?::(\d{1,2})(?::(\d{1,2})(?:\.(\d{1,3}))?)?)?)?\s*$/;
  var parts = rex.exec(str);
  var dt = null;
  if (parts) {
    dt = new Date(+parts[3], // Year
      +parts[2] - 1, // Month
      +parts[1], // Day
      +parts[4] || 0, // Hours
      +parts[5] || 0, // Minutes
      +parts[6] || 0, // Seconds
      +parts[7] || 0 // Milliseconds
    );
  }
  return dt;
}

function test(str) {
  var dt = parseIt(str);
  console.log(str, "=>");
  console.log("   " + String(dt));
  console.log("   (" + (dt ? dt.toISOString() : "null") + ")");
}

test("foobar");
test("31-08-2016");
test("31/08/2016");
test("31/08/2016 9");
test("31/08/2016 9:25");
test("31/08/2016 09:25");
test("31/08/2016 09:25:17");
test("31/08/2016 09:25:17.342");
```

The regex *looks* complicated, but it's really just a bunch of capture groups nested inside non-capturing, optional groups. [Explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/gY6jC6/1)

or

B) Use a library (like [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com)) that lets you parse a string by saying what the format is.

Comment: The *Date* object is probably the most neglected part of the language, hopefully the *Temporal* proposal will fix that.

Comment: @RobG - Hopefully, though as far as I know it doesn't expand the parsing features, and the API is complex enough that I suspect people who struggle to use `Date` will struggle to use Temporal. :-| Hopefully I'm wrong about that.