# Why Date("26/02/2017").getTime() return NaN?

Tags: javascript, date, gettime

I simply run:

```
new_time = new Date("10/02/2017").getTime()
```

and it return - `1506891600000`

But, whet i run:

```
new_time = new Date("26/02/2017").getTime()
new_time = new Date("25/02/2017").getTime()
new_time = new Date("16/02/2017").getTime()
new_time = new Date("15/02/2017").getTime()
```

it return - `NaN`

What's the problem with `Date().getTime()`?

Comment: Try `02/15/2017` or `2017/02/15`. Or if you don't have to use values like this `new Date(2017, 02, 15)` would be even more accurate. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: ^^ just remember if you do that multi-part constructor, the months start with 0 = January.

Comment: In American date, you have month/day/year. And JavaScript is based on it. You can use ISO date too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Use an ISO format: `new Date("2017-02-10").getTime()`

Comment: Better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39244286/error-parsing-date-string-with-new-date

Comment: @Gilsdav: Not officially, the `Date` constructor is **not** defined as accepting `mm/dd/yyyy`. I've never met a JavaScript engine that didn't do so (even in non-U.S. locales), but that's different.

Comment: @alex—that will be parsed by most browsers as UTC, so will produce a local date for 9 Feb where the host is set to a timezone west of Greenwich.