# Stange javascript Date behaviour on particular dates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

i noticed a strange behave of javascript on manging this particular Date

```
"31-12-2017 23:59:59"
```

i have an API which i call and returns me some date as String, and i have to cast them to Date using js.

My code is like that

```
while (i<array.length){
                                array[i].start_date = new Date (array[i].start_date);
                                array[i].start_date.setHours(array[i].start_date.getHours()+1);
                                array[i].start_date = $filter('date')(array[i].start_date, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");

                                array[i].end_date = new Date (array[i].end_date);
                                array[i].end_date.setHours(array[i].end_date.getHours()+1);
                                array[i].end_date = $filter('date')(array[i].end_date, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");  
                                $scope.insSupplies.push(array[i]);

                        i++;
                    };
```

where array is the API i'm questioning.

The problem here is that when my code tries this

```
array[i].end_date = new Date (array[i].end_date);
```

on this date

```
"31-12-2017 23:59:59"
```

`array[i].end_date` becomes `Invalid Date`

How that happens?

EDIT:

```js
var date = "31-12-2017 23:59:59"
var dateSplitted = date.split("-");
var dateInverted = dateSplitted[1] +"-" +dateSplitted[0] +"-"+dateSplitted[2];
dateSplitted = dateInverted.split(" ");
alert(dateSplitted[0]+"T"+dateSplitted[1]+"Z");
alert(new Date(dateSplitted[0]+"T"+dateSplitted[1]+"Z"));
```

I implemented this rough method to parse my date, but i don't get how is wrong
Any help?

Comment: It's not this particular date. Any date in this format is invalid. It also says `25-08-2015 18:30:10` is an invalid date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what is the issue going on here. But the solution is your month and date format is wrongly placed  to convert.

Your date format should be `12-31-2017 23:59:59` instead of `31-12-2017 23:59:59`. like `mm/dd/yyyy`. may be it's works like your browser default date format.

you can check this below alert results.

```js
alert(new Date("12-31-2017 23:59:59"))// this is a correct format.

alert(new Date("31-12-2017 23:59:59"))// here `31` is month. The default month count is 12. but here it's automatically add 19 months into 12 month(31-12). So it will go to future year.

alert(new Date("13-12-2017 23:59:59"))// here you can check the result of Jan month 2018
```

### EDIT:

You should swap the month and date before convert. try this below code

```js
 

var date= "31-12-2017 23:59:59".split("-");

var newDate = date[1] +"-" +date[0] +"-" +date[2];

alert(new Date(newDate));
```

Comment: ok, got the problem, but there is a way i can parse the string above to a Date format?

Comment: I have edit my answer. @Anon let me know if you have any clarification.

Comment: that is a very tricky method, still fits for my case

Comment: @Anon  If you got your answer, then don't forget to mark as this an answer. thanks

Comment: @Anon & Ramesh: Beware that this is still parsing a string that isn't in a specified format, and thus you don't know whether it will be parsed in UTC or local time. To take it all the way, replace the space with a `T` and add a `Z` to the end to ensure UTC (because there was a bug in the ES2015 spec that said no `Z` on a date/time string meant local time, where it should have said UTC to match ISO-8601 [and does, in ES2016+] -- and sadly, yes, some implementations did what the spec said rather than what ISO-8601 defined). Or of course, just finish parsing it (which isn't hard).

Comment: Yeah! @T.J.Crowder . I agree. That's why I up vote you.  Your answer have the explanation of the defect. in my answer I have fix it.

Comment: @RameshRajendran: Again: You *mostly* fixed it, but you're still relying on unspecified behavior in your solution. A complete solution (like, say, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39244384/157247)) wouldn't rely on unspecified behavior.

Comment: @RameshRajendran & T.J. Crowder  i have to thx both of you for your help, i'll parse my date using your help

Answer (score 7):

That date isn't in any format that the `Date` object is required to parse, nor a format that is commonly supported even though it isn't required.

The **only** format `Date` is required to parse is the ISO-8601 subset [defined by the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-date-time-string-format). That date, in that format, would be `"2017-12-31T23:59:59"`.

For historical reasons, `xx-xx-xxxx` is commonly treated as a date in U.S. format (even in non-U.S. locales), which is `MM-DD-YYYY` rather than the <s>more rational</s> format common outside the U.S. of `DD-MM-YYYY`. But even that isn't at all universal, and again isn't specified. The only format that isn't specified but *is*, as far as I know, universal is `DD/MM/YYYY` (again U.S. format).

Comment: thx for the answer, so how is possible that other date given by that API is correctly parsed? should i think of "luck" attribute?

Comment: Maybe worth adding a link to the MDN on dates too? Specs can be a bit much to read :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: @Anon: Well, if it were (say) `01-12-2017`, it would be parsed on many (but not all!) implementations as January 12th, 2017 (rather than December 1st, 2017). But since the first number is 31, which isn't a valid month, `31-12-2017` doesn't parse at all.

Comment: so how can i "force" js Date to parse on dd-MM-yyyy format? is my filter in the above code enough?

Comment: @Anon: You have to write the code to parse it yourself, and use the multi-argument form of the `Date` constructor. There are dozens of questions and answers here about how to do that. Edit: LOL, [I've even written one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39244384/157247) I should have closed this as a duplicate (in retrospect, that's obvious, but I got caught up in the "it's only certain dates" and then...)