# Invalid Date on validation Date of js

Tags: javascript, date

that's the continuation of a  [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45997207/stange-javascript-date-behaviour-on-particular-dates/45997412?noredirect=1#comment78955615_45997412)

I'm trying to parse String that comes from an API to be able to use js API to parse them as a date

I ended up writing a code like this:

```js
var date = "01-09-2017 23:59:59";
var dateSplitted = date.split(" ");
var dateSplittedBySpace = dateSplitted[0]+"T"+dateSplitted[1]+":000Z";
     dateSplitted=dateSplittedBySpace.split("-");
var finalDate = dateSplitted[1]+"-"+dateSplitted[0]+"-"+dateSplitted[2];
console.log(finalDate);
console.log(new Date(finalDate));
     
dateSplitted= date.split("-");
var yearHour= dateSplitted[2].split(" ");
     
finalDate= yearHour[0]+"-"+dateSplitted[1]+"-"+dateSplitted[0]+"T"+yearHour[1]+":000Z";
console.log(finalDate);
console.log(new Date(finalDate));
```

with 2 different approaches, but none of the dates I created seems good for the Date API of js, any help?

Comment: What about this `new Date( "01-09-2017 23:59:59")`

Comment: @JaydipJ that was the problem of the previous question, is not a valid format if i try with "31-12-2017 23:59:59"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you're looking for.

```js
function stringToDate(dateString) {
  const
    dateAndTime = dateString.split(' '),
    dateParts = dateAndTime[0].split('-');

  // The array will be [01 (day), 09 (month), 2017 (year)], by reversing the 
  // array the date parts will be in the order as needed [year, month, day].
  dateParts.reverse();

  const
    // ES6 syntax.
    //isoDateString = `${dateParts.join('-')} ${dateAndTime[1]}.000Z`;
    // Old school syntax
    isoDateString = dateParts.join('-') + ' ' + dateAndTime[1] + '.000Z';
    
  return new Date(isoDateString);
}
  
console.log(stringToDate('01-09-2017 23:59:59'));
console.log(stringToDate('31-12-2017 23:59:59'));
```

Comment: this does not work on  isoDateString = `${dateParts.join('-')} ${dateAndTime[1]}.000Z`

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand what you mean. What exactly doesn't work? The method returns a Date object for the provided string.

Comment: that $ is not replaced by any function or something,just part of the string, are you using jquery?

Comment: It is ES6 syntax, you could write `isoDateString = dateParts.join('-') + ' ' + dateAndTime[1] + '.000z';`.

Comment: I've updated the answer for ES5 syntax. For more info on template literals from ES6 check here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 0):

`:000Z` is wrong format, should be `.000Z`

Since you have `YYYY-MM-DD` format I suggest you to split everything and generate new `Date` object

```
var dateStr = "01-09-2017 23:59:59"; 
var reg = /(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/;
var dateArr = reg.exec(dateStr); 
var date = dateArr[3] + "-" +
           dateArr[2] + "-" + 
           dateArr[1] + 'T' + 
           dateArr[4] + ':' + 
           dateArr[5] + ':' + 
           dateArr[6] + '.000Z';    

console.log(new Date(date));

// => Sat Sep 02 2017 02:59:59 GMT+0300 (IDT)
```

<kbd>[Demo Fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/dde8msj5/)</kbd>

---

If you don't need TZ, you can remove `'.000Z'`

<kbd>[Demo Fiddle 2](http://%20jsfiddle.net/8jagpy46)</kbd>

Comment: this is a good solution except for the fact it adds the time zone

Comment: Well, i thought this is what you wanted, do you want in UTC?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```js
array = "01-09-2017 23:59:59".split(' ');

date = array[0].split('-');
time = array[1].split(':');
realDate = new Date(date[2],new Number(date[1])-1,date[0],time[0], time[1],time[2],0);
console.log(realDate.toString());
```

Also, it would help if you tell the API. Specifically the language for the api. Usually a Long timestamp would work with almost all apis.

Comment: there's an error here, the date return the month of october

Comment: It's because the value is 9 and JS months are 0 based. 0=Jan, 1=Feb, and 9=Oct. It should be `parseInt(date[1],10)-1`.

Comment: this could be the best answer here if doesn't have the GMT, i specifically asked for a Z timezone

Answer (score -1):

Since that is not an actual date format. You can use moment to format as you like

```js
var date = "01-09-2017 23:59:59";
var date2 =  new Date(date);

var dateFormat = "YYYY-DD-MMTHH:mm:ss";
var finalDate = moment(date2).format(dateFormat);

console.log(finalDate);
console.log(moment.utc(date2).format(dateFormat)); //for UTC
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Moment comes in handy at most times. Check [momentjs.com](https://momentjs.com/) for more options

Comment: Instead of the 1st of September you get a Date object for the 9th of January.

Comment: Sorry, there is still something wrong with your solution. The console logs the time as '23:59:00'. What happened to the 59 seconds from the input string?

Comment: updated that was a typo in the format.used `SS` instead of `ss` for seconds. fixed now @Thijs

Comment: I am really sorry but the problem isn't fixed. `date2` still is the 9th of Jan, all you did is download 16KB of JavaScript to format the string. When you want to do further calculations with the date object it will still give you the wrong date.

Comment: yes, since the input is not a valid date. all you guys are just splitting formatting. I just provided an alternate method to format. that's it. format `date` it using moment for final output. don't use `date2` that's an intermediate variable thats it