# Datetime diff in minutes

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have 2 `DateTime` field in a form, and I want the difference between these 2 fields in minute.

I tried to parse `DateTime` into `Date` but it's not working :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#mybundle_evenement_button").click(function () {
            var field1 = $("#mybundle_evenement_debut").val();
            var field2 = $("#mybundle_evenement_fin").val();
            var date1 = new Date(field1);
            var date2 = new Date(field2);
            alert(date1);
        });
    });
</script>
```

If I `alert()` date1, it shows `Invalid Date`. 
But if I `alert()` field1, it shows `15/09/2017 13:32` (format is : days/months/year hour:minutes).

Is it possible that `new Date(field1)` isn't working because of the format ?

I know that if I succeed to parse DateTime into `Date`, it'll be easy to have the difference in minutes, but I don't understand why it says `Invalid Date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm` isn't a valid date format for [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

You have to format your date to a valid [Date Time String Format](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15), for example:

```
var field1 = $("#mybundle_evenement_debut").val();

var ISODate1 = field1.replace(/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/, "$3-$2-$1")

var date1 = new Date(ISODate1);

alert(date1) // => Fri Sep 15 2017 13:32:00 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It's depend on your browser. I'll suggest to use the standard format is `'2013/12/09 10:00'`. 
Okay! come to the point. You need to manually format the date from my latest answer regarding this same kind of  issue. Please take a look at this link : **[Stange javascript Date behaviour on particular dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45997207/stange-javascript-date-behaviour-on-particular-dates/45997412#45997412)**

---

And you could try this below code for getting the date difference in minutes.

```js
 
var startTime = new Date('2013/12/09 10:00'); 
var endTime = new Date('2014/12/09 10:00');
var difference = endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime(); 
var result = Math.round(difference / 60000);

alert(result);
```

Comment: Ok as expected the problem is the format. The format is dd/mm/yy because I want to. In france, we have days first. I'll try to have the standard format to use Date(myDate).

Comment: YES! But if you want you can format the data manually from which is I am mentioned  a link in my answer @BastienNicolau

Answer (score 0):

The problem is about the format you are getting the date from the field. `new Date()` don't accepts this format. I think the best is to parse the `string` yourself. If the format is always the same just use `new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)`.

```
var day = field.splice(0,2); field.splice(0,1);
var month = field.splice(0,2); field.splice(0,1);
var year = field.splice(0,2); field.splice(0,1);
var hour = field.splice(0,2); field.splice(0,1);
var minute = field.splice(0,2);
```